# Numerate by Group in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (DF) like the following:

```
      [ID]   [Value]  
[1]   ID_1    5
[2]   ID_2    6
[3]   ID_2    9
[4]   ID_3    1
[5]   ID_3    445
[6]   ID_3    10
          etc.
```

What i need is to numarate the observations (backwards) by the ID column so that the solution looks like:

```
       [ID]    [Value]  [Observation] 
  [1]  ID_1     5       1
  [2]  ID_2     6       2
  [3]  ID_2     9       1
  [4]  ID_3     1       3
  [5]  ID_3     445     2
  [6]  ID_3     10      1
            etc.
```

All that in a flexible way because the number of observations can differ. It would be great if that would be possible 
with a base R solution.
I found a solution which does that counting up from 1:

```
DF$Observation<-do.call(c, lapply(unique(DF$ID), function(enum){
  seq(sum(DF$ID==enum))
}))
```

Well if it Helps in any way originaly the data ist stored in a list with every "ID_" as a num vector.
Perhaps it is easier to start here and wirte code which saves the values in "backwards" order.

```
myList <- list(ID_1 = 5, ID_2=c(6,9),ID_3=c(1,445,10))
```

Comment: As soon as you utter or think the phrase "by group" you should be thinking of `ave`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try with `ave`

```
 DF$Observation <- with(DF, ave(Value, ID, FUN= function(x) rev(seq_along(x))))
 DF$Observation
 #[1] 1 2 1 3 2 1
```

#### data

```
DF <- data.frame(ID=c('ID_1', 'ID_2', 'ID_2', 'ID_3', 'ID_3', 'ID_3'),
     Value=c(5,6,9,1, 445, 10), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. `ave` is such a useful function.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I was able to modify my own code (just adding the `rev` command) before the `seq` part but your standalone answer works just great, too!